# .htaccess: clean url with smart filters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Spent 2 days mixing and matching rules from stackoverflow and other sites but there's no luck, a part will work and the other part will not :( I want something like "smart" rule to filter errors.

- example.com/**user/** or example.com/**user** needs to point to same location e.g. example.com/profile.php?viewuser&who=$1

Problem: In my current setup, it just loop to white screen when theres a trailing slash so i decided to "manually" remove trailing slash. By the way the white screen produced when view-sourced contains the correct html markup - it just was not displayed i dont know why.

- example.com/**user**/*notexistingurl* must throw an error but will retain the url structure of links, to be at the example.com/ level.

Problem: Mine was broken to example.com/**user**/links.php instead of example.com/links.php

By the way ***user*** is a variable, so it could take ***simonsoft***, ***anotheruser***, etc. In case you see that theres nothing wrong in my site, its actually fixed when i used `<base>` tag. removal of that tag makes a mess then. Im looking for someone to provide some corrections on my rules below and possibly to not rely on `rewritebase` or `base` tags

Here is my existing .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# Some "static" links
RewriteRule about$ 22688.html [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule privacy$ 77.html [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule terms$ 867.html [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule login$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule logout$ logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule register$ register.php?do=regterm [NC,L]
# Quick login url
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+):([^/]*)$ login.php?do=login&loguid=$1&logpwd=$2 [NC,L]

# The vanity url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_.]+)$ profile.php?do=viewuser&who=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_.]+)/friends$ profile.php?do=friends&who=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't any rule for `/messages/user` OR `/messages/user/2` here.

Comment: @anubhava i updated the question, analogy of /messages/user or /messages/user/2 will be applicable to the last line in htaccess code i posted. i'll stick to the main problem instead.

Comment: That's the thing reading your post multiple times I couldn't figure out what exactly is the `"main problem"`

Comment: @anubhava the problem is that it looks "ok" but when i remove the `<base>` tag on my html files, then htaccess rules go crazy. so with my edited post, i want someone to help me if the .htaccess needs modification, and i want the desired effect as posted above. i hope you can finally get what i mean.

Comment: `<base>` can only be removed if you use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: @anubhava in short, my .htaccess is _correct_, but i need to prepend a `/` on my links e.g. `href="/file.ext"` instead of my existing `href="file.ext"`s? pls confirm, thanks

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct.